Firefox: Developer Tools window stuck in full-screen mode
I use the Developer Tools in Firefox a lot, and somehow they got stuck in full-screen mode, I cannot remember how I pulled that off. Nothing helps: double-clicking the title bar, Windows+ArrowDown, and the helper icons in the top-right corner have disappeared: 
All I can do is enter or quit using F12, or move the window to a different screen/workspace using Ubuntu keys. Restarting Firefox doesn't fix it, when I type F12 the window is maximized once again.
How can I deactivate full-screen?
Possibly useful info: Firefox Snap for Ubuntu, 131.0.3 (64-bit), canonical-002 - 1.0

There are possibly two causes, the window manager or Firefox itself.

Losing window controls on the title bar, which you don't have, is probably a window manager thing. If you turned title bars off, I'd presume you can turn them back on. I don't use Ubuntu, but the Internet suggests ...

... Settings Manager → Window Manager Tweaks → Accessibility → Hide title of windows when maximized ...


...


... to unmaximize, minimize, or close ... Alt-Space or right click ... also Alt-F4 ...


There is a way to turn the title bar of the main window off, but it doesn't apply to the devtools window, at least not in Windows. Double check that it doesn't apply in Ubuntu.

☰ > More tools > Customize toolbar
Make sure Title Bar is checked in the lower left.

If the title bar was turned off in Firefox, it should have turned off the title bar in the main window, too, but you say it's the only window without one.

See if the problem goes away in Troubleshoot mode.

☰ > Help > Troubleshoot mode...
Click Restart
Click Open

Follow the same steps to turn off Troubleshoot mode. If the problem goes away in Troubleshoot mode, it's definitely a Firefox setting problem, somewhere.
It won't be userChrome (legacy CSS), but you can check, anyway.

Type about:config in the URL bar
Search for toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets. You won't have to get all the way there.
If it's true, make it false and restart Firefox.


See if the problem exists in a new profile.

Type about:profiles in the URL bar
Click Create a New Profile
Give it a name. Click Finish.
Probably set your old profile as the default, because creating a new  profile makes the new one the default automatically.
Launch the new profile in a new browser. See if the problem exists.

If the problem doesn't go away with a new profile, then it's definitely a window manager problem.
If the problem goes away with a new profile, but didn't in Troubleshoot mode, you can try "refreshing" your profile, but that's kind of a sledgehammer solution. Follow the same steps as for Troubleshoot Mode, but click Refresh Firefox instead of Open.
Refreshing resets the profile to "factory default," except it keeps your bookmarks, history, passwords, and cookies. However, extensions, site settings, UI customization, non-standard about:config changes, etc., will be gone and have to be redone.



Docking works, no problem, but I have to check the html very often and I use the debugger quite a lot. I don't want to reduce the browser screen (the app we build is a full-screen app), so I need the tools on the side, in a separate window.
I'll check the first suggestion, thanks! By the way, it's the only window without a title bar...

OK, I added more things to try.

It's probably not Firefox. I am a Skype user as well. When my colleague shares his screen with me, there are two windows displayed when Skype doesn't have focus: the main Skype screen and a sub-window (pop-up sort of) with a minified screen. and I just noticed that that minified screen is stuck too: I can't move it, I can't resize it, nothing works, except for closing it. I'll be trying your other suggestions in due course!

I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, the issue seems to have disappeared. I'll be back if/when it happens again.

@D.Bugger, Roger.
